# Troubleshooting a USB 3.0 device that connects as USB 2.0 on a USB 3.0 port

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, usb-3

So on my 5 year old laptop when I connect a 3.0 USB drives, the device connects as USB 3.0 and I can utilize its full speed.

When I connect a 3.0 HDD to the 3.0 port, it sometimes connects as 3.0/2.0 with the HDD sometimes failing to respond. This used to not happen in the beginning when I got the laptop, which leads me to think the USB port is worn out and is unable to provide enough power since the issue persists with a different hard disk drives and different USB cables and there is no issue on another laptop.

I am trying to connect the Intel® RealSense™ Depth Camera D435 which requires a USB 3.0 connection to fully function but it always connects as USB 2.0 on my 5 year old laptop, but works fine on another laptop.

So I want to know is the issue related to power or the USB 3.0 data pins contacts on the port?

I am guessing the cause is insufficient power to the device as small usb 3.0 drives connects fine.

Comment: Is your laptop USB connector a standard "A" connector (original style), or a mini connector?  With A connectors, if you insert a USB 3.0 plug very slowly, sometimes the delay before the extra pins connect causes it to be recognized as USB 2.0 before you're done plugging it in.  So if you're being super extra careful, you might be causing it yourself.  Otherwise, 2.5" USB hard drives typically don't need more power than a USB 3.0 port provides (or they come with their own power pack).  (cont'd)

Comment: With USB 2.0, there was rampant abuse of the spec with non-compliant devices.  It's not as bad with USB 3.0.  Devices should be self-powered if their requirement exceeds the port power limit.  If you have multiple devices that work on another computer but not the laptop, I'd suspect the laptop.  It's possible that the USB port is worn or dirty, especially if 3.0 devices connect as 2.0.  Or, internal electronics for the port could be failing, there could be a loose internal connector, there could be an internal power problem, etc.  (cont'd)

Comment: Does the laptop have more than one USB port?  If so, do they all behave the same?  Beyond a few pretty basic checks, this kind of problem will be difficult for people to diagnose remotely.  If it isn't obvious, you may need to take it for service.

Comment: The laptop is a standard "A" Connector. I have already tried plugging in fast multiple times. I have two 3.0 USB ports and both have similar issue, just one of them fails most of the time to load the HDD (it connects as 2.0 USB Device and the Disk appears in explorer but is not accessible, takes forever to load upon clicking it)

Comment: I will try getting some isopropyl alcohol to clean the ports and maybe get a Dual Male to Female USB cable for testing before I take it for service.

Comment: Even if one port fails more often than the other, if both ports have issues, it's a good bet that it is an internal problem.  It could be electronics failing, bad "wiring" of one kind or another (internal connectors, cold solder joints, etc.), a power problem, etc.  I don't think there's any way for readers here to figure out what it is.  That's the kind of problem where a technician will need to open it up and run tests.  The thing with a laptop is that all of the possibilities typically come down to replacing the motherboard because almost everything is on it.  (cont'd)

Comment: It could be something like a failed capacitor that could be replaced, but very few service shops do board-level repairs.  They swap boards and send the damaged one to a refurbisher that is set up to repair them.  It isn't unusual for laptops to start failing in 5 yrs.  A replacement motherboard will be a substantial fraction of the cost of a new laptop, and it will be a reconditioned board with a 90 day warranty.  On a laptop of that age, other components are end-of-life, too, so it usually isn't a good investment to put that kind of money into a repair.

Comment: Which OS is running on your old laptop? Is it OEM OS, or did you have some re-installations and upgrades?

Comment: The original OS was Windows 8. I had long upgraded it to Windows 10. I tried running the Camera on the laptop with Ubuntu, but the device still connected as 2.0 USB device.

Comment: Currently i have tested with more devices, all tested 3.0 USB Flash drives and external SSD connects successfully. Half of tests with 3 different external HDD had issues connecting (stuck loading, connecting as 2.0, disconnecting in between). The camera always connects as 2.0 USB device.  
I have ordered some isopranol and a dual male to female USB 3.0 Cable for testing. Will tell the results later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, getting a dual male to female USB 3.0 Cable fixed the issue. 
I had the 3.0 USB port of the male cable connected to a 3.0 port on the PC and the 2.0 USB male of the cable connected to 2.0 port of the PC. HDD and the Camera is now working stable.
I think the issue was most likely the port being unable to provide enough current.